# Amazon S3 server side encryption

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to turn on server side encryption when uploading a file asynchronously to Amazon S3. I have the file upload working but cannot figure out where to specify the encryption option. Any ideas?

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyID, awsSecretAccessKey, regionEndPoint))
{
   using (TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
   {
     await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, objectkey);
   }
}
```

Edit:

I realize that Amazon has documentation on how to specify encryption using a putObjectRequest but was wondering if it can be done using the FileTransferUtility.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingDotNetSDK.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingDotNetSDK.html, specifically, this:

> When using the high-level multipart upload API (see [Using the High-Level .NET API for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html)), the TransferUtility class provides methods (Upload and UploadDirectory) to upload objects. In this case, you can request server-side encryption using the TransferUtilityUploadRequest and TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest objects.

It should be something like this (sorry, not in a place to test it at the moment):

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = existingBucketName,
    FilePath = filePath,
    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
    Key = keyName,
    ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256
};
fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest, someCancelToken);
```

Comment: There's a better example here on how to use the `TransferUtilityUploadRequest`: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxPJDGHVNCWHUJ/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-Windows-Store-and-Windows-Phone

Comment: I'm trying to do with using ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AWSKMS and it's not working